# Why does `Class<T> == Boolean.class` cause a compiler error when `T extends Comparable<? super T>`?

Tags: java, generics, java-7, comparable

I'm using generics to abstract out Comparable data types, as illustrated in the code supplied below. This case arose from a Java Swing component, specifically from attempting to adapt table model to use generics.

I have a working solution to that problem (Case 3A below). However, during the process of arriving at that solution I became confused by the behavior of the compiler when I changed the class signature from `T extends Comparable<T>` to `T extends Comparable<? super T>`.

Why does the compiler want Comparable to be a raw type (Case 3A below)? I expected the class signature to work (Case 6A, `Class<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`), but it requires a cast and causes a compiler error when using `if (type == Boolean.class)`.

Why do cases 2B, 3A/B, and 4A/B allow `if (type == Boolean.class)` but cases 1A/B, 2A, 5A/B and 6A/B cause a compiler error? Specifically, I'd like an explanation of this error in the case of 2A vs. 2B, which share the same class signature.

The runnable test cases are below. The external `Score` and `DetailedScore` classes are supplied to demonstrate a case involving inheritance, which highlights the difference between Case A and Case B.

**`ComparableTest.java`**

```
public class ComparableTest<L, T extends Comparable<? super T>> // Case A
//public class ComparableTest<L, T extends Comparable<T>> // Case B: Works when used without inheritance.
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ComparableTest<String, Boolean>(new String("B"), Boolean.TRUE);
        new ComparableTest<String, Float>(new String("F"), new Float(1f));
        new ComparableTest<String, Score>(new String("S"), new Score(5f));
        new ComparableTest<String, Score>(new String("D"), new DetailedScore<String>("DS.S", 5f));
        new ComparableTest<String, DetailedScore<?>>(new String("DS"), new DetailedScore<String>("DS.DS", 5f));
    }

    public ComparableTest(L label, T value)
    {
        // Case 1A: Compiler Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable> to Class<T>
//        Class<T> type = value.getClass(); // Q: Why can't I use Class<T>?

        // Case 2A: Compiler Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable> to Class<T>
//        Class<T> type = (Class<T>) value.getClass(); // Case 2B: This works if 'T extends Comparable<T>' (see note in class declaration above).

        // Case 3A: Compiler Warning: Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized
        Class<? extends Comparable> type = value.getClass(); // Q: Why must Comparable be a raw type here?

        // Case 4A: Compiler Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable> to Class<? extends Comparable<?>>
//        Class<? extends Comparable<?>> type = (Class<? extends Comparable<?>>) value.getClass();

        // Case 5A: Compiler Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable> to Class<? extends Comparable<T>>
//        Class<? extends Comparable<T>> type = (Class<? extends Comparable<T>>) value.getClass();

        // Case 6A: Compiler Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable> to Class<? extends Comparable<? super T>>
//        Class<? extends Comparable<? super T>> type = (Class<? extends Comparable<? super T>>) value.getClass();

        // Case 1A, 2A: Compiler Error: Incompatible operand types Class<T> and Class<Boolean>
        // Case 2B, 3A/B, 4A/B: OK.
        // Case 5A/B, 6A/B: Compiler Error: Incompatible operand types Class<capture#4-of ? extends Comparable<T>> and Class<Boolean>
        if (type == Boolean.class)
        {
            System.out.println("Treating " + label + " as boolean (" + type.getCanonicalName() + ")");
        } else if (type == Float.class) {
            System.out.println("Treating " + label + " as float (" + type.getCanonicalName() + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Treating " + label + " as (" + type.getCanonicalName() + ")");
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

**`Score.java`**

```
public class Score implements Comparable<Score>
{
    private Float value;

    public Score(Float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score o)
    {
        return this.value.compareTo(o.value); // for brevity
    }
}
```

**`DetailedScore.java`**

```
public class DetailedScore<D> extends Score
{
    private D detail;

    public DetailedScore(D someDetail, Float value)
    {
        super(value);
        this.detail = someDetail;
        return;
    }

    public D getDetail()
    {
        return this.detail;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getClass()` returns a `Class<?>` not a `Class<T>`... But you can safely cast it.

Comment: @assylias Yes, Case 6A in the example casts to `Class<? extends Comparable<? super T>>`; however, this still causes a compiler error when using the `==` operator.

Comment: which compiler version?

Comment: @bayou.io Oracle JDK: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)`, `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)` on  Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See javadoc of [`Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--), the return type of `value.getClass()` is `Class<? extends |T|>`, i.e., `Class<? extends Comparable>`.

The type of expression `value.getClass()` undergoes wildcard capture before it's used further; therefore we see the captured type `Class<capture#2-of ? extends Comparable>` in messages.

The question surrounding `type==Boolean.class`, according to JLS[#15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3), depends on whether one type can be casted to another. Casting between 2 types is forbidden if it's provable at compile time that it is impossible; in which case `==` test is forbidden too. That makes sense.

However, JLS[#5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) might be a little sloppy. First, lets follow its exact words. `Class<a1>` can be casted to `Class<a2>`, only if type arguments `a1, a2` are not provably distinct. Obviously we don't want `Class<Boolean>` casted to `Class<FLoat>`.

For your case between `Class<T>` and `Class<Boolean>`, according to JLS[#4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), they are not provably distinct, due to `Boolean<:Comparable`. Therefore it should be allowed. Your compiler forbids it, but javac8u45 allows it.

Follow the same reasoning, `type==Boolean.class` should be allowed in all your cases. That is the behavior of IntelliJ. But javac8 does not; it forbids case 5 and 6.

Reexamining JLS[#4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), `Class<? extends Number>` and `Class<? extends Runnable>` would be incomparable, because bounds `Number` and `Runnable` have no subtype relationship. That would be too restrictive, because there could be a subclass of Number that implements Runnable. Indeed, javac8 does allow the two types to be casted or compared.

Interestingly, javac8 would forbid comparing `Class<? extends Boolean>` and `Class<? extends Runnable>`. Obviously, the fact that `Boolean` is final is a factor here. That sounds a lot like JLS[#5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).

It appears  that for "provably distinct" testing, javac8 sometimes uses casting conversion test.

While this whole thing is a mess, fortunately we can always add an intermediary cast to a common supertype to resolve all the issues, so this is not too big of a problem

```
Dog dog = (Dog)(Animal)cat;

Dog.class == (Class)Cat.class
```

Comment: Thank you, this is explanation I was seeking. Also, I was not aware that intermediate casting made a difference to the compiler - I assumed those were removed during compilation.

Comment: The explanation is ... it's a mess :) e.g. how can we cast `Boolean` to `Comparable<?>`, by the rules of JLS#5.5.1? The spec is not self consistent. The underlying research is lacking. The compilers are fumbling.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler warnings are not the same as errors... for example, your "case 2A" will compile... it will generate a warning but will give you a usable class file. These are generally due to erasure, which is a complicated topic that I don't pretend to fully understand.

But for example, when `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, if you have `value` which is declared as a `T`, of course you should be able to cast `value.getClass()` to `Class<T>`. But due to erasuer the compiler only remembers that `value.getClass()` should return a `Class<? extends Comparable>`, so it warns you that you should be careful when casting to `Class<T>`. You can shut up the warning, if you're sure about things, by using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, like this:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> type = (Class<T>)value.getClass();
```

A good IDE (like Eclipse) will suggest this annotation as a possibility to fix the warning; if you aren't using a good IDE I'd suggest you start.

So let's talk about the actual errors instead. In Java you can only check for object equality if two things are the same type or are assignable to the same type. For example, this works:

```
public static class Foo {

}

public static class Bar extends Foo {

}

public static void main(String...args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Bar b = new Bar();

    if (f == b) {

    }
}
```

because, at the point of comparison, `f` could be a `Bar` under the covers; it's allowed. On the other hand, this does not work:

```
    Boolean b = Boolean.FALSE;
    Integer i = 5;

    if (b == i) {  // ERROR

    }
```

There is no way these two could ever be equal. It's an error.

From the compiler's point of view, `Class<T>` and `Class<Boolean>` (which is the type of `Boolean.class`, natch) are different types. If `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, they are not assignable to each other, since `Boolean` implements `Comparable<Boolean>`; it does **not** implement `Comparable<? super Boolean>`. So you cannot check for equality with `==`.

(If `T extends Comparable<T>` then that is compatible with `Boolean`, and you can do that comparison.)

So don't use `==`. Use `if (type.equals(Boolean.class)) {...}` instead, and the compiler will be happy and you'll be happy.

Comment: Interesting. The Swing classes in the JDK use the same `==` comparison (see Line 113 in [AbstractListModel.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/e8d7c5715d59/src/share/classes/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.java)). I'm fairly certain that is why I was using this operator.

Comment: That line is `if (listeners[i] == ListDataListener.class) {...}` and `listeners` is declared as an `Object[]`, which means `listeners[i]` is an Object... in that case, `ListDataListener.class` is assignable to `Object` (as is every non-primitive), so the comparison is valid. `listeners[i]` could well be the class `ListDataListener`.