# Difference between downcasting Class vs downcasting Interface in Java?

Tags: java, android, interface, casting

why can we cast from a Super Class down to a Subclass like so:

```
Object o = getStringObject();
String str = (String) o;
```

but then use the same principle to cast an interface DOWN to a sub-type E.G.?

```
InterfaceType anInterface;
anInterface = (InterfaceType) SubClassVar;
```

so EXAMPLE 1 is all fine and dandy. What i Don't understand is that if an interface is a super-type of a class that implements it, then how do we not have a ClassCastException when we downcast the class to the interface, if within the hierarchy the interface is higher? i read somewhere that there's a difference between casting via classes, and interfaces, but of course they didn't feel like explaining why, so i'm left in the open. Thanks, Stack!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that `SubClassVar` IS a `InterfaceType`? Then there's no use for the cast.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis SubClassVar is a class that implements InterfaceType

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Maybe i need more information, but if you develop for android, this is the communicator pattern, used to talk between an activity and a fragment.

Comment: There is no need for a cast in your second snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you up-casted to the interface because it is higher in the hierarchy than the (presumed?) implementer of that interface, `SubClassVar`. Additionally that cast isn't even needed because implementations of an interface can be talked about in terms of that interface anyway, without cast syntax.

You *can* downcast an interface just as you did with the subclass. Here is an example:

```
interface I1 {}
interface I2 extends I1 {}

class I2Impl implements I2 {}

class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      I1 test = new I2Impl();
      I2 test2 = (I2)test;
      I2Impl test3 = (I2Impl) test2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the programmer explicitly cast one type to another, it's usually because the programmer knows more about the runtime type of the object than the compiler. The compiler could choose to allow any cast, because the smart programmer says so. However, being Java, the compiler will try to catch and prevent obvious mistakes.

A cast between two types is not allowed, if it is obvious that no object can belong to the two types at the same time; or in another word, the intersection of the two types is empty. For example, we cannot cast between `String` and `Integer`; nor `String` and `Runnable`. However, `Number` and `Runnable` can be cast to each other, because conceivably there could be an object in both types.

Also, identity comparison `a==b` is only allowed, if A and B can be cast to each other, for the same rationale. `==` isn't allowed if the compiler knows they cannot be the same object. see [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3)

The exact algorithm is very complicated - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1 Note that the algorithm is symmetric - A can be cast to B, if and only if B can be cast to A. The text of the spec is not very good and likely contains bugs (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31300973/2158288) )

A "downcast" is when the target type is a subtype; an "upcast" is when the target type is a supertype. Upcasting is usually unnecessary, however there are [cases](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/KVmmgeSCHkA) when it is needed.